# simple.JSONArray para json.JSONArray

Tags: java, json

Estou com um problema. 
No mesmo código, meio que preciso utilizar tanto o simple.JSONArray quanto o  json.JSONArray. Não tenho como importar os dois, então estou tentando utilizar o simple.
Acontece que, quando faço um request, a resposta é um json que o java diz ser simple, então não consigo usar o outro.

No trecho do codigo que estou tendo problemas, estou a ler um arquivo. Ele volta como um Object, que preciso transformar em json. segue o trecho:

```
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray queues = (JSONArray) parser.parse(new FileReader("file.json"))
```

Aparece o seguinte erro (na primeira linha do treco acima):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.json.simple.JSONArray cannot be cast to org.json.JSONArray
```

Se uso o simple, da problema em outra parte do codigo.Estou usando mvc, então fica complicado criar um novo arquivo só pra fazer um método...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você consegue importar e usar os dois sim. Basta importar normalmente e, na hora de usar no código, passar a referência completa, incluindo o caminho do pacote. Algo como:

```
org.json.simple.JSONArray json = new org.json.simple.JSONArray();
```

Se, em outro local do código, você precise usar a outra classe JSONArray, basta da mesma forma passar a referência completa. Por exemplo:

```
org.json.JSONArray json2 = new org.json.JSONArray();
```

Quanto ao seu código atual, não há nada a fazer. O erro de casting é bem claro.